# PIG dynamic parameters

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I am trying to read value from a hbase table and decalre the value as a param

```
rawConfig = LOAD 'hbase://mytable.config'
      USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
        'm:config',
        '-gte myTsFlag -lte myTsFlag}'
      ) as (
        tsConfig:chararray
      );

rawCache = FOREACH rawConfig generate (IsEmpty(tsConfig) ? '0':tsConfig) as lastTs;
```

now i want to set the value of `rawCache.$0.lastTs` as the paramter so that i can use it while loading next table

This does not work

```
%declare myConfig rawCache.$0.lastTs;
raw = LOAD 'hbase://mytable.users'
      USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
        'm:1',
        '-minTimestamp $myConfig'
      ) as (email:chararray);
```

Any ideas on how can i use the value of previous table?

Am relatively new to Pig so I may be completely wrong as well :).

Answer (score 0):

quoting the statement should work:

```
 %declare myConfig 'rawCache.$0.lastTs'
```

Comment: still getting the same
`error pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[m:1, -minTimestamp rawCache.$0.lastTs]'`

Comment: Sorry, that was definitely the wrong answer. I did not notice that your parameter is a pig command.